# How to write general integration function in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, integral, function-composition

I would like to write a function in OCaml that will calculate the definite integral for the given function. The problem is that I aim for the following syntax:

```
let sphere r phi theta = r *. sin phi *. cos theta in
let dphi = 10 in (* number of parts *)
let dtheta = 10 in (* number of parts *)
let zero = 0.0 in
let two_pi = 2.0 *. 3.14159
in

integral zero two_pi (integral zero two_pi (sphere 3.0) dphi) dtheta
```

The problem is that using rule like trapezoidal rule I need to write something like:

```
0.5 *. (f a +. f b) *. d
```

Which expects that the `f a` and `f b` are **not** partially applicated functions.

I don't expect that the result from the last `integral` function call will return me a float number, I'm totally fine with some functional.

I've realized that the question is very unspecific. Let me restate it in a more general way:

I have a function `float->float->float` which after the application of `integral` function should give me `float->float`. It should be general, so the `integral` of `float->float` should result in `float`.

The problem is that I need subtract two functions of the same order: `f(a) -. f(b)`, where both of them could be `float->float->float`, `float->float` or even `float->float->float`.

To decrease the order of a function I need a signature like: `(float->'a->float) -> ('a->float)`.

Is this even possible? Specifically in OCaml?

The more I think about this problem of having *one* function calculating the integral that can be chained, the more it seems like an impossible task/stupid way to do it.

In fact I've implemented this but using my own data type (called `function_type` which can be `Scalar3rdOrderFunction`, `Scalar2ndOrderFunction`, `Scalar1stOrderFunction`, `Scalar0thOrderFunction`). But for the prize of polymorphism the compiler cannot warn me when I try apply the integral three times for function `float->float->float`.

Comment: I see no problem with the information you provided, it is very much possible.

Comment: lukstafi, I see one. Look, with function of two arguments you can't evaluate `(f lower -. f upper) /. 2.0` because type of `f lower` is not `float`.

Comment: I see, `sphere 3.0` is not a function of one argument. What about: `integral zero two_pi (fun th -> integral zero two_pi (sphere 3.0 th) dphi) dtheta`.